# How to represent variable length sequence in BCNF relation design?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization

Suppose I have a sliding puzzle, or a turn based game, or navigating a maze, essentially a scenario in which we care about what the moves are but also about their order, and furthermore there is a variable number of them, how can we design a schema that stores puzzle/game/maze information such that it is in BCNF?

Suppose, as a working example, the schema is something like:

`Puzzle = (puzzle_id, time_limit, solved, moves)`

where `moves` is a sequence of actions, of variable length like `'tile_1_down; tile_2_up; tile_18_right; ...'`.

How do we express this idea of an ordered sequence combined with a variable length in a BCNF design?

Comment: Q&A is an ineffective way to learn; it's to get unstuck. Prefab comments: 1. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. 2. Dozens of published academic information modeling & DB design textbooks are online free in pdf. stanford.edu has a free online course. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this situation is modeled in the following way:

```
Puzzle  = (puzzle_id, time_limit, solved)
Move = (puzzle_id, number_of_move, move)
```

with `puzzle_id` primary key in `Puzzle`, `puzzle_id, number_of_move` primary key for `Move`, and `puzzle_id` inside Move foreign key for `Puzzle`.